# Mirror DFS configuration data between 2 servers/ sites

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, dfs

I have 1 Windows 2008 R2 server in Site A running Domain Integrated DFS in 2008 mode with a Single Namespace with a large number of DFS Targets all configured to point to a share on our NetApp SAN.

Step 1.
I want to initially copy this configuration data across to a 2012 server in Site A preserving all the configuration data.

Step 2.
I need to mirror this configuration to a 2nd server in Site B so we dont have a single point of failure for the DFS namespace.

For Example. A user in Site B would "connect" to the DFS server in Site B, but if that site was down, it would attempt to connect to the Server in site A and vice versa.

Note im not interesting in replicating actual Data here, just the configuration. Our NetApp SANS have mirroring which take care of that.

Is this possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With domain-integrated DFS (which you have), your domain controllers take care of this already. As long as you have domain controllers in both sites and your AD sites and subnets properly configured, you're good to go. Your clients simply ask the nearest DC for the required paths.

Simply point your clients to

```
\\<domain.fqdn>\<DFS name>
```

Comment: Hi Trondh. Thanks for the reply. Does this mean then that I dont need to setup DFS on a server in both sites? My thought was that if the server with DFS went down, because it was the host for the namespace and the DFS Targets (which point to the san) then noone would be able to access anything?

Comment: Correct. In a domain-based setup, your domain controller are basically hosting the dfs namespace and provide clients with correct paths to the "real" data.